# Cakephp3 Layout size with zurb foundation

Tags: cakephp, zurb-foundation, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

Im wondering how to deal with a problem in cakephp3 thats annoying me. I understand it uses the superb Zurb Foundation for layouts.

if i bake my CRUD actions of a typical controller i get 4 view files.  But each view file has 4 separate layout sizes;

Here is an add view;

```
<nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), ['action' => 'index']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Questions'), ['controller' => 'Questions', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Question'), ['controller' => 'Questions', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="users form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add User') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('username');
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Heres the index view;

```
<nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New User'), ['action' => 'add']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Questions'), ['controller' => 'Questions', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Question'), ['controller' => 'Questions', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="users index large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <h3><?= __('Users') ?></h3>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('id') ?></th>
                <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('username') ?></th>
                <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('password') ?></th>
                <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('created') ?></th>
                <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('modified') ?></th>
                <th class="actions"><?= __('Actions') ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $this->Number->format($user->id) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($user->username) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($user->password) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($user->created) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($user->modified) ?></td>
                <td class="actions">
                    <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $user->id]) ?>
                    <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $user->id]) ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $user->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $user->id)]) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="paginator">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous')) ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >') ?>
        </ul>
        <p><?= $this->Paginator->counter() ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Similarities:**
If you look at the first line of the both code samples youll see;

```
<nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
```

This code sample is in both views in fact its in the **edit** and **delete** as well.

**Maintaining 4 Views:**
By setting the `large-3` value to `large-2` in one view file means that ill have to do the same for the other 3?

Is there some way to make one change that effects all 4 views? Am i missing something here.

**Whats the solution?**
How can i maintain a consistent layout without the headache of having to customize 4 files. 
I know i could stick an element in there but that cant be the correct solution?

Comment: Do you intend to change the class of the Nav element dynamically under conditions or to change the Bake templates?

Comment: i just want a way to not have to modify 4 views all the time..if i decide to resize the layout elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the class in your AppView and echo it out in your view.